# Where is the header file ptp_clock_kernel.h?

Tags: kernel

I was not able to locate the header file "ptp_clock_kernel.h" in the header version 3.19.0-31-generic. Is it something we need to add it to the kernel image ourself?

as requested, the output of "apt-cache policy linux-headers-3.19.0-31-generic":

```
linux-headers-3.19.0-31-generic:
  Installed: 3.19.0-31.36
  Candidate: 3.19.0-31.36
  Version table:
 *** 3.19.0-31.36 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy linux-headers-3.19.0-31-generic`

Comment: Try `dpkg -L linux-headers-3.19.0-31-generic | grep ptp_clock_kernel`

Comment: Forget it, there is no header file with this name. o_O

Answer (score 0):

The header file isn't in this kernel package, please don't ask me why.

- `linux-headers-3.13.0-24` (Trusty)
- `linux-headers-3.19.0-15` (Vivid)
- `linux-headers-4.2.0-16` (Wily)

but not for `linux-generic-lts-vivid`.